# Meaning of "<<<HTML" in code example

Tags: php

I am trying to include some javascript for the google analytics ecommerce tracking.

In the example code I see something like this, in which I have replaced the variables with my own.

```
<?php
 function getTransactionJs(&$order) {
        return <<<HTML
        ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
          'id': '{$order->ord_order_numner}',
          'affiliation': 'Marcella',
          'revenue': '{$order->total_payment}',
          'shipping': '0',
          'tax': '0'
        });
        HTML;
    }


echo getTransactionJs($order);
 ?>
```

However I met with a syntax error. May I ask what is the meaning of

```
return <<<HTML
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Heredoc: http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc. Btw. this is a question about PHP syntax, not Google Analytics, so the tag is somewhat misleading.

Comment: @EikePierstorff that'd be an answer

Answer (score 1):

It's a way to define a string on multiple lines. Your string begin juste after the `<<<HTML` and ends at `HTML;` The `HTML` word can be replaced by whatever you want.

See [Heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Answer (score 0):

It’s PHP’s [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax. I’m not a fan of it though.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested read the manual, but consider not to use this kind of syntax.

To make your life easier - in most cases the problem is with text indenting.

```
HTML;
```

Must be at the start of the line not indented!